# ESP8266 ESP-12 Connection

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am connected with my ESP-12 through a programmer and all the AT functions work correctly. However I do not get a connection when connecting to the ESP8266 module.

*I have done the following:*

Set the mode both: `AT+CWMODE=3`

Connect to an Access Point: `AT+CWJAP="<name>","<password>"` (Responds with WIFI Connected and WIFI Got IP)

Set the Access Point: `AT+CWSAP = "<other_name>","<password>",<channel>,<password_security>`

So at this time it should be connected to my local network and I can connect to it through wifi on my laptop. However when I connect to it, it says 'Connected, No Internet' (The network the esp8266 module is connected to, has internet).

When I troubleshoot problems it says DNS is not responding.

Does anyone have a clue what to do next? Or what I might do wrong?

Comment: ESP8266 isn't a router. It doesn't route your laptop traffic to the AP with the internet.

Comment: Also this problem has nothing to do with Arduino.

Comment: It is an Arduino like module which can be set with Arduino and is able to be set as Access Point so it should be able to connect and have internet,..

Comment: make sure to set your AP to the same channel as the STA.

Comment: @dandavis Thanx for the good tip! :) But I indeed made sure the channel was the same.

Comment: You mention that in many different circumstances that you are somehow "connected" to something. But I have no idea what you mean. (Perhaps you tied them together with a piece of string? Or wired together two terminals but left both devices turned off?) You need to say not that you were "connected" but that you performed a specific test and got a specific response, e.g., "From my laptop, with IP address 1.2.3.4, I pinged 1.2.3.5 and got back a response." Also, giving us a link to the documentation from which you're working would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the ESP8266 behave as a router, see Google for details.  By default it won't do this.

You need to create two separate WIFI networks and then tell the ESP to 'route' traffic between them.

Your ESP needs to form one network (STA mode?).  Your laptop needs to be on one network with the ESP.  The laptop needs to be configured to use the ESP as the gateway and unless your ESP has a DHCP server the laptop needs a static address.

Your ESP also needs to be a client to you router's network, and needs to take an address from the Router's DHCP server.